# Trying to pause animation through scripting, but it flickers between states instead

Tags: c#, loops, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I have some code that will pause an animation when part of my UI is active

```
public void Update()
{
    if (tutorialModal.activeInHierarchy == true)
    {
        Debug.Log("The tutorial panel is active!!");
        nac.UserClickedPauseButton();
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("The tutorial panel is not active, I repeat NOT ACTIVE!");
    }
}
```

The `UserClickedPauseButton` code is as follows

```
public void UserClickedPauseButton()
{
    if (animator.speed > 0f)
    {
        // we need to pause animator.speed
        rememberTheSpeedBecauseWeMightNeedIt = animator.speed;
        animator.speed = 0f;
        playImage.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        pauseImage.gameObject.SetActive(false);

    }
    else
    {
        // we need to "unpause"
        animator.speed = rememberTheSpeedBecauseWeMightNeedIt;
        playImage.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        pauseImage.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

Now, when the GUI element is active, the animation doesn't pause, it flickers between being paused and unpaused.

[image]

All I want is for the background animation to pause when the tutorial is open.

Comment: Update means EVERY FRAME. if you think about it you're doing that thing EVERY FRAME. you only want to do it ***one when it changes*** .. right?  that's the secret here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `paused` boolean variable. Otherwise `UserClickedPauseButton()` is called on every frame when `tutorialModal` is active.

```
bool paused = false;

public void Update()
{
    if (tutorialModal.activeInHierarchy == true && !paused)
    {
        Debug.Log("The tutorial panel is active!!");
        nac.UserClickedPauseButton();
        paused = true;
    }
    else if(tutorialModal.activeInHierarchy == false && paused)
    {
        Debug.Log("The tutorial panel is not active, I repeat NOT ACTIVE!");

        // And remember to call UserClickedPauseButton here too, 
        // so animation is unpaused when tutorialModal is not active.
        nac.UserClickedPauseButton(); 

        paused = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: perfect, many thanks. I was certain it needed a bool in there I just wasn't sure where to put it.